# Uniqueness of comultiplication for sufficiently connected spaces of restricted dimensions

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

I'm working through an introductory homotopy theory book (Arkowitz) for self-study, and I'm a bit stuck on the following exercise.  Not a lot of machinery is available at this point in the book. I'm not seeing how to leverage the $(n-1)$-connectivity or the dimensional restrictions. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious:

Let $X$ be an an  $(n-1)$-connected space with $n \geq 2$. Prove that if $dim\ X \leq 2n-1$, then there is a comultiplication on $X$. If $dim\ X \leq 2n-2$, prove that any two comultiplications on $X$ are homotopic.

---

For context, I am including an image of the previous exercise (2.6) and a possibly relevant proposition (2.4.6, also referred to as 8.2.1) from the chapter containing the exercise.

[image: Previous exercise (2.6)]

[image: Proposition 2.4.6 (also known as Proposition 8.2.1)]

Comment: The idea is to start with exercise 2.6. The assumptions let you calculate the connectivity of $X\vee X\hookrightarrow X\times X$ and apply Proposition 8.2.1.

Comment: Thanks. If I am understanding your suggestion, Exercise 2.6 would apply if I could use Proposition 8.2.1 to demonstrate a bijection between $[X, X \vee X]$ and $[X, X \times X]$. But $X$ is not a CW complex, so I'm not really sure how to use the proposition.  Even if X was a CW complex, I'm still also unclear on how to piece together the dimensionality/connectivity constraints to employ the proposition. I think that I am still misunderstanding. Could you elaborate a little please?

Comment: If you consider general spaces, you need a concept of dimension for these spaces. What does the book say about it?

Comment: Quote from the book : 2.1 Introduction 
NOTATION AND STANDING ASSUMPTIONS 
From this chapter on, most of the spaces that we consider will be based 
and path-connected and have the based homotopy type of based CW complexes.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this out, I'll informally sketch an answer based on the comments I received. We regard $X \vee X$ as the sub-complex of $X \times X$ with support $X \times \{*\}\space \cup \{*\} \times X$, where $i: X\vee X\longrightarrow X \times X$ is the inclusion map. Since $X$ is $(n-1)$-connected we may assume, without loss of generality (Cor $2.4.10$), that $X^{(n-1)}$ (the $(n-1)$ skeleton of $X$) $=\{*\}$. Then $(X \vee X)^{(2n-1)} = (X\times X)^{(2n-1)}$. Thus $i$ is a $2n-1$ equivalence.

By proposition $2.4.6$, $i_*: [X, X\vee X]\longrightarrow [X, X\times X]$ is surjective when $dim\space X \leq 2n-1$ and is a bijection when $dim\space X \leq 2n-2$.

Let $\Delta:X\longrightarrow X\times X$ be the diagonal map. When $i_*$ is surjective, $\exists c\in [X, X\vee X]$ with $i \cdot c$ homotopic to $\Delta$. Then by exercise $2.6$, $c$ is a comultiplication.

When $i_*$ is a bijection, such a $c$ is unique (up to homotopy).